# How to speed up the creation of a dictionary?

Tags: python, sage

I have a code to create a dictionary like this.

```
z=1
for r in xrange(m):
        D[z]=r
        z=(z*g)%p
```

For large m (greater than 10^6), the loop is taking too long to compute. I have to optimize this code for values of m upto 10^10. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: At a glance, I suspect that z's value will repeat with a period smaller than p. I wonder if you can take advantage of this fact and get O(p) execution time. That would be quite nice if p is much smaller than m.

Comment: @Kevin if g is a primitive generator over p (with p prime), it won't... this looks like crypto-type math to me (specifically discrete log over finite fields).  Avirup: can you provide a little more context for why you're doing this, and if you just do D[r] = r, is it still taking too long to computer (I'm curious if you're hitting some issue with the dictionary assuming a certain default size and then having to dynamically grow in a poor way)

Comment: Basically I am implementing the BSGS algorithm for discrete log computation. A for loop like this 
for i in xrange(10**9): continue is also taking around 40 sec to compute. Yes D[r]=r is also taking same amount of time (just a little less).

Comment: create the dictionary one time and save the results in a json file ... it should only take a fraction of a second to load the json file .... although 10^10 is a whole lot of memory(20GB asuming 1byte keys and one byte values (which is probably smaller than what you are actually using) ... if it has that many entries in the dictionary ...

Comment: Interesting... the answer is probably numpy (since that's usually the answer when it comes to getting python to run with heavy math) but I don't know the details.  Also note that Pollard's Rho should have the same big O as Baby Step Giant Step but can be run in parallel if you do get this to work and want to go the next step.

Comment: if thats how long it takes for just the loop to run ... thats pretty much how long its going to take ...

Comment: I think this sort of thing is the reason why Python has C bindings.

Comment: It seems wasteful to create a dictionary that's indexed by sequential keys like that. It likely be a lot faster to just use a `list` or `tuple` (although there will be zeroth entry).

Comment: @martineau actually in the next step I have to search entries in the dictionary by the key value. Since dictionaries are hash tables, it will take O(1) time to search. That's why I am using dictiionary

Comment: @AvirupMullick I'm not sure that `dict[somekey]` is faster than `list[someindex]`.

Comment: If the keys are indices, just use `sequence[key]` to directly access any entry you wish. Sequences are also O(1), but without the overhead of hashing & hash tables -- so are smaller and faster to create.